# What is the :index option used for in fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the :index option in fields_for used for in Rails 3? I am reading the documentation but I don't understand.

I am trying to use the radio_button helper but it doesn't work, all radio buttons can be checked.

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer_form| %>
   <%= answer_form.text_area :description, :rows => 2 %>
<% end %>
```

I get names like this `question[answer_attributes][0], question[answer_attributes][1], ...` Where does the numbers come from and what are they for? Are they array indexes?